# How to run Python 3 http.server on port 80 without root?

Tags: python, http

I want to run Python 3 **http.server** on **port 80**, **without** running it as root and without installing any extra software (e.g., authbind). I'm using Arch Linux. I would prefer to do this with systemd and have it autostart on boot, if possible.

I made this simple wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /srv/http/mywebsite/
python -m http.server 80
```

I can run it with this unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python 3 http.server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/website_start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That "works", but it is not secure. If I add a user and group, it fails with "Permission denied" (I guess because port 80 needs root privileges).

```
[Unit]
Description=Python 3 http.server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/website_start.sh
User=http
Group=http

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The errors are:

```
Jun 23 00:58:57 myvps systemd[43060]: http_python_server.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied

Jun 23 00:58:57 myvps systemd[43060]: http_python_server.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/website_start.sh: Permission denied

error: connect_to website port 80: failed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give your service process the capability to use ports <1024, but no other root privileges:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python 3 http.server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/website_start.sh
User=http
Group=http
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Read `man 7 capabilities` if you want to know more.

The `/sbin/getpcaps` command can be used to query the capabilities available for a process by its PID. Normally root-owned processes have a long list of capabilities and non-root processes have none at all.

Comment: That works. Is there any security risk compared to running http.server on port 8080 and using `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`?

Comment: Well, your `http.server` and any of its child processes will have the ability to use any free port number, but that's all. So if you don't use any network services that base their security on the assumption that ports < 1024 can only be used by root and so can be implicitly trusted, you are fine. But technically, the iptables solution might be ever so slightly more secure.